# Fit Texture background on Screen in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, background, c#-3.0, guitexture

I'm new in Unity and trying to add texture background. I know this question has been asked many times but still I'm having problem. I've set background texture following instruction given in answer of this thread.

[GUI Texture as Background](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/606271/gui-texture-as-background-is-hiding-other-objects.html)

And it's looking something like that :

[image]

the image which I'm trying to adjusting as background is :

[image]

Here is my main camera settings :

[image]

and background camera settings :

[image]

To adjust texture to fill background , I tried to take help from following link but I couldn't understand it.

[Background does not fit on screen](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/633855/my-background-image-doesnt-cover-the-whole-screen.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use texture as a background , add a cube object and load texture as its material.